# Extrusion without self intersection

Tags: graphics, 3d, mesh

I have a mesh constituted by triangles or quadrilaterals, and I need to extrude it.

Unfortunately, I have discovered that the mesh has inner cells, and then I produce self-intersecting solids. Here is a cat that contains inner triangles for what I can only suppose is the mouth and tongue. A closer image may shed some light on the mesh.

[image: clip]

[image: zoom]

Is there a library that can help me produce extruded solids that are not self-intersecting? VTK and CGAL both say that can produce self-intersection.

As an alternative, is there a know algorithm that can help me?

Comment: pictures to accompany your question could be helpful

Comment: @Makogan you're right, I have added two images, hoping it may clarify the problem.

Comment: Here's a wild complicated idea, there is a paper about computing the winding number of vertices in 3D. You could maybe use that and delete all inside vertices, and then try to stich what's left?

Comment: @Makogan thanks for the answer. Well, not that complicated, but it would change the mesh drastically. I am hoping to leave the mesh as it is, if possible.